# Problem creating new channel application with dbmigrate

Tags: intershop

After trying to create a new application with dbmigrate, the application appears, but without access privileges tab in BackOffice.
Classes used in dbmigrate file were the following:

```
Class1 = com.intershop.component.mvc.dbmigrate.preparer.AddChannelPreparer
Class2 = com.intershop.beehive.core.dbmigrate.preparer.domain.CreateApplicationPreparer
```

What I noticed in the database is that all other applications have two rows in the application table except this one.
One is for the application and the other is for the storefront application.
The storefront application is missing.

My question is which classes should I use to create an application with dbmigrate?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new storefront application in an existing channel or are you trying to create a new channel with a new storefront application?

Comment: I am trying to create a new storefront application in existing channel.

Answer (score 2):

First of all let me explain those two preparer classes that you have been using:

- *AddChannelPreparer* as the name suggests creates new channel(s) with the given list of (storefront) applications (property `apps`). It skips creating a channel if that one already exists.
- *CreateApplicationPreparer* creates an application in the given site and the given owning domain. That doesn't necessarily needs to be a storefront application. Let's just say it's an application in a site.

What you are missing when trying to use above preparers in your dbmigrate configuration are some required additional steps - e.g creating repositories, creating application domain relations and most importantly the management application for your storefront (that's why you're missing the permissions tab).

Bottom line is, I don't know any preparer that triggers these steps. My safest bet is that you use the `ExecutePipeline` preparer to execute `ProcessApplication-Create` pipeline in *sld_ch_base*. As that is the pipeline that is executed from the backoffice when a user manually creates a new storefront. Make sure that you execute the pipeline within the backoffice application context.